# GMail gem cannot find file uploaded by carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying out a new gem called "gmail". I am trying to send a message with an attachment file however I seem to encounter this error everytime:

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/upload/avatar/4/filename.png

the line of code where I attach this image is noted below:

```
def send_message
    params = message_params

    u = Upload.create(avatar: params[:file])
    u.save!
    # puts "Upload: #{u.avatar}\nLocation: #{Rails.root.join(u.avatar.url)}"

    email = @gmail.compose do
      to "#{params[:to]}"
      subject "#{params[:subject]}"
      body "#{params[:message]}"
      add_file "#{Rails.root.join(u.avatar.url)}"
    end
    email.deliver!
    flash[:success] = 'Message sent!'

    Upload.destroy_all

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Please help I've been stuck at this for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the path was lacking a bit...managed to solve it by changing the path to:

```
path = "#{Rails.root}" << "/public" << u.avatar.url
```